# Simulate turn sequence in turn-based game with one human player

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm working on a turn-based card game. The main loop is simple, I have this structure (it's very simplified to be brief):

```
while (!gameEnded) {
    for (Player *pl in players) {
        Action *a = [pl askForAction];
        self [manageAction];
    }
    if (some condition...) {
        gameEnded = TRUE;
    }
}
```

If all the player's are computer players there's no problem but if I want to have a human player, the askForAction method should "pause" the loop and let the player to select the action (pushing a button or touching a card...)

How can I do that? I've been "googling" it but I can't find anything. I suppose that the solution should be to use NSThread (or NSRunLoop maybe...) but I can't find an approach. Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What you've created is very similar to a 'traditional' game engine, based on loops.  But since you're working in iOS without any need for real-time updates, it makes sense to use the event-driven approach instead.

Answer (score 3):

Like Adam says, an event-driven model is probably best. However, I just want to emphasize how simple it is to resolve this, and there's no need for anything like `NSThread` or `NSRunLoop`.

You simply stop iterating when you get to a human player, and then start iterating again once you get an action from them:

```
- (void)nextTurn
    while (!gameEnded) {
        Player *pl = [self nextPlayer];
        if (pl.isHuman) {
            break;
        } else {
            Action *a = [pl getActionFromComputer];
            [self manageAction:a];
        }
    }
    if (gameEnded) {
        // game over
    } else {
        // Set up your UI so it can get an action from the player.
        // Your UI should be set up so that once it gets an action,
        // it does [self manageAction:uiAction] then [self nextTurn]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The way I would do it (there may be better answers) is to use an event-driven model rather than running in the loop.

In the delegate (or wherever), keep track of the current player (index into the players array). Call `[[players objectAtIndex:currentPlayer] askForActionWithDelegate:self];`

In the delegate, have a receiver (you can use `manageAction`), and when the user has performed the action, call `manageAction`. In manageAction, check for victory condition and advance `currentPlayer`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay. I've applied this approach and that's what I want. The way I've made it is as follows:

```
- (void)consumeTurn:(int)idPlayer {
    if (![gameEnded]) {
        Player *p = [getPlayer:idPlayer];
        if (![p isHuman]) {
            /** Do some stuff **/
            consumeTurn:[getNextPlayer];
        } else {
            /** Show UIView with buttons for human player interaction **/
        }
    } else {
        /** Game is ended... **/
    }
}
```

And then in every button, the action associated to each button is:

```
- (IBAction)playerAction {
    /** Do some stuff **/
    consumeTurn:[getNextPlayer];
}
```

I call "consumeTurn" method in my principal ViewController (viewDidLoad).

Thank you every one for your help